# Super Privilege on MySQL Database hosted under GoDaddy

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

My website hosted with godaddy shared hosting. In Mysql database I want to perform following triggers

```
CREATE trigger totalSpent BEFORE INSERT on orders

FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.totalSpent=NEW.quantity*NEW.amount ;
```

But it gets end up with this error message.

> ## 1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

What I need to do to get super privilege over my database.

Comment: What did GoDaddy support say when you asked them?

Comment: @KenWhite Thet are saying you need to to contact your server administrator

Comment: No, they're not. You should actually contact them. If it's your site they're hosting, they are aware you *are* the server administrator.

Comment: @KenWhite they are saying in shared hosting user will not get super privilege over database

Comment: Then you have your answer, right? You cannot get super privilege over your database while GoDaddy is hosting it.